# What are strategies to simplify a vectorized raster layer?

Tags: raster, qgis-3, simplify, vectorization

For a GIS web viewer I am building, I plan to use large sets of vector data on coral reefs (source: [Allen Coral Atlas](https://www.allencoralatlas.org/)). When viewing the downloaded data, it seems that the original source was raster data which has been vectorized (see image below).

[image: Example of benthic coral reef data in Subtropical Eastern Australia.]

I expect that the high number of (unnecessary) vertices in the polygons increases the file size of the vector layer. I am limited by the amount of data I can upload to our GeoServer, and would like to keep the file size of my vector data as small as possible.

**What are some good strategies to simplify such a vector layer in QGIS, in order to reduce file size?** In this case, it does not matter if I lose some detail, e.g. removing small polygons or cutting of polygons. It is only important that I keep the rough outline of the various types of coral reefs. Below a rough sketch of what I have in mind (with the red lines connected the 'updated' vertices):

[image: Rough sketch of a simplication.]

Note: I am aware of the `simplify` tool in QGIS. However, using this tool does not yield the result I want, because the outline of the coral reefs is not maintained and the polygons get a very 'unnatural' shape (see image below).

[image: Running the QGIS simplify tool with the Douglas-Peucker algorithm.]

Comment: Lower the tolerance setting in simplify

Comment: Can you share your data, at least a sample of it?

Comment: I'd first try GRASS v.generalize with the Lang algorithm using  some different tolerances.  There are other parameters for that, and then many other algorithms to try.

Comment: Further to BERA's comment, you might get a more satisfactory result by using a different simplification algorithm in the *Simplify* tool.  You can select from 3 different algorithms with the dropdown.

Comment: @BERA I've have tried out different tolerance settings, but they do not result in a satisfactory result. The polygons remain blocky and unnatural-looking.

Comment: @Babel The data is freely available in the atlas: https://www.allencoralatlas.org/atlas/#1.00/0.0000/-145.0000.

Comment: @John Thank you for the suggestion, I will try that out!

Answer (score 3):

I have a suggestion.

First, use the "densify by count" tool, adding one vertex. Then, use the "extract vertices" tool.

The new point feature you create will have one vertex at each midpoint of every segment.

create a bool field and apply this expression:

```
if(vertex_part_index % 2 = 0, True, False)
```

Then delete the ones with "true" value assigned in the field you just calculated.

Now use the "points to path" tool, and since you're representing a polygon, check the "create closed paths" box, and order expression using the `vertex_part_index` field.

Finally, use the "smooth" function, with 3 iterations for example. That should work. I tested here and it was fine.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice technique to make the polygons more visually appealing, it looks great. However, unfortunately it doesn't address the aspect of file size reduction. There are probably many more vertices than the original polygon.

Comment: @Matt, indeed. 
To reduce the file size, you can
- reduce iterations when using `smooth` from `3` to `1`.
- don't use smooth
- instead of using `2` in `if(vertex_part_index % 2 = 0, True, False)`, use a bigger integer.

Comment: Although @Matt is right, visually this is exactly what I was looking for, so great suggestion.